# Is there any light plugin for image crop and resize in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a project. Where I have a section of profile picture upload. I want to resize and crop a image while uploading. I'm using CakePHP 3.4.

Comment: https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this list of curated CakePHP Plugins.

https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#imagery